# Counterexample of a theorem for characteristic function.

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, characteristic-functions

> Let $X$ be an $\mathbb R$-valued random variable and let $f(t)$ be his characteristic function. If $f$ is derivable up to order $k$ in $t=0$ , where $k$ is even, then $X$ has a finite $k$-th expectation.

I ask for a counterexample where $k$ is not even.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1426310/75923).

Comment: drhab can you give me an hint to prove that the characteristics function is derivable in 0 ?